# Android Room not sure how to convert cursor to method's return type issue

Tags: android, android-room, android-cursor

I've seen lots of questions on here and none of these answers resolved my problem.
Here's my DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT name FROM Recipe where category == :category")
fun getByCategory(category:String): List<String>
```

I'm trying to get a list of recipes that are contained in that category. I get a compile time error that says:

C:...\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\mitch\rcp\RecipeDAO.java:18: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (void).

But my return type is not void? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you have a double equals. Only one is required

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Yeah its the same.